# Set wickedpicker default time to empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [wickedpicker](https://ericjgagnon.github.io/wickedpicker/) jQuery plugin on my site, and it keeps adding the current time to my input. How do i set to to blank by default? Below is my options

```
 var options = { 
        title: '', //The Wickedpicker's title,
        showSeconds: false, //Whether or not to show seconds,
        clearable: false //Make the picker's input clearable (has clickable "x")
}; 

 $('#timepicker, #timepicker_hourly').wickedpicker(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default property/method to have empty value by default. wickedpicker Adds class hasWickedpicker to attached input. You can clear the value of such inputs using `.val()`:

```
$('#timepicker, #timepicker_hourly').wickedpicker(options);
$('.hasWickedpicker').val('')
```

Comment: ah thanks, thought i missed something in the documentation